# Find break even point and then calculate the difference of adjacent cells, both of which are dynamic?

Tags: excel, sumifs, excel-match

I have a stream of cashflows going all across row 37, where each column represents a month (ie. B37 is cashflow in january, C37 february, etc.), and I want to have a function that finds what month these cashflows go from negative to positive, and then calculate the difference between those two months (the last negative month, and the first positive month). I currently have:

```
=INDEX($B$2:DQ$2,MATCH(TRUE,B37:DQ37>0,0))
```

Which is successfully returning the month of break even, but now I want it to also calculate the difference between the last negative and first positive month. To further complicate things, the "break-even point" will not always be the same, as it changes based on the input parameters. For example, if the cashflow in cell F37 is negative then then the cashflows starting with G37 are positive, I want to return the month associated with G37 (say, cell G2) and then calculate the difference between cell F37 and G37. However it will not always be F37 & G37...depending on input values on a different sheet, the point where the value goes from negative to positive might be I37 and J37.

I feel like there is a way to do this using `SUMIFS` in combination with `INDEX` and `MATCH`, but I just cannot pinpoint exactly how to do it.

Comment: Well, how about providing a bit more detail about the conditions that determine whether it might or might not be one cell or the other. That would certainly help. Explain the business logic, explain the input, explain the expected output. Put that into your question, not a comment.

Comment: @bish thank you for the feedback, this is my first time using this resource. I have edited my question to include the current formula I am using and added some more background (it wont allow me to add a photo)

Comment: @teylyn thanks for the comment. I apologize for the poor explanation. I have added more to my question, which hopefully clarifies what I am doing and planning to do. Thanks for your engagement, I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Match() returns the position of the found value in the range. So if you successfully find the last negative or the first positive value, you can use pretty much the same formula by adding or subtracting a number to find adjacent cells.

Your explanation is still very wordy and not clear. I assume that the formula you have for what you call break even is the first positive value. To calculate the difference between that and the last negative value, which by definition must be one cell to the left, then subtract 1 from the result of the Match function

```
=INDEX($B$2:DQ$2,MATCH(TRUE,B37:DQ37>0,0))-INDEX($B$2:DQ$2,MATCH(TRUE,B37:DQ37>0,0)-1)
```

Comment: thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking to do. In the event that I have to post a question in the future, I will try to make it more clear and less wordy. It is unfortunate that they don't allow new users to post photos, as that would be infinitely clarifying. Cheers.

Comment: If you post a link to an image that is on a file sharing site, then people can follow it. In many cases, people will edit your post and put the image in the post. Now, the other thing you do is: when somebody solves your problem, you mark that post as the answer. That how to say thank you on this site. Once you have more reputation points you can also upvote a post to thank people whose posts you consider useful.